# How to receive a POST response in PHP via URL

Tags: php

The info that I found hasn't worked for me or I simply don't understand what I'm reading.

A POST request is being made to a specific location (URL) and a response will be sent back to a URL that I must specify, existing on my domain. (eg `www.mysite.org/answers/answer.php`)

What do I need to do in order to extract every piece of information that is being sent to that location?

Right now I am redirecting from the form page after the form (having been submitted via POST) has been submitted by a user to the `answer.php` which checks `if isset($_POST["submit"])` but it's not giving me anything.

Furthermore, if I had many users doing requests what URL would I use so that each user is redirected to their own answer page?

Comment: please post the html code or tell what method are you using for posting the form? Get or Post?

Comment: you only get `GET` responses via url; see ref: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_get.asp; or `REQUEST`, as The Complete PHP Newbie said. (what i name, ain't it, bro'?)

Comment: not only GET but REQUEST too

Comment: So you're submitting to othersite.com/service.php which posts the results to mysite.org/answer.php? This is asynchronous, there is no direct way of grabbing the data and displaying it to the submitter in one go.

Comment: so what should I do? The site REQUIRES that I give them a URL to send a reply to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need some kind of storage mechanism (session, database, etc) and a token (session id, primary key, etc).

1. Generate a token on your website when the user submits the data (for example, use session id).
2. Submit this token to the other website along with the submitted data.
3. Send the user to a waiting page (see below).
4. The other website will (hopefully) echo back the token to your answer script along with response data.
5. In your answer script, save the response in the storage using the token (for example, use session_id(token) function to load the user session, then set session variables).
6. In the waiting page, continuously poll the storage to see if the response has arrived. You could use a meta refresh tag that refreshes the page every 10 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

"submit" is probably the name of the submit button? This value is only present in the request if the form is indeed submitted through the button. You could have multiple buttons, in case only the name of the clicked button is present in the post data.

Furthermore, if the user submits by just pressing enter when the last input field is selected, the form is also submitted, but no button was pressed. In this case, the name of the submit button isn't available at all in $_POST (nor $_REQUEST).

Long story short: don't check for the name of the button. Just check for available field data. 
If you want you can loop through the post data:

```
foreach ($_POST as $postkey => $postdata)
{
  // $postkey contains the key
  // $postdata contains the value
  // any code here is repeated for every posted value.
}
```

Or, as long as you're just testing:

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

Answer (score -1):

instead of Post use $_REQUEST, it will work for both Post and Get

Comment: when submitting the form or when retrieving the response?

Answer (score -1):

On your html form add something like this.

```
 <form action="answer.php" method="post">
 <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="true" />
```

Then in answer.php

```
 <?php
 if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) {
   print_r($_POST);
 }
 ?>
```